# Not able to copy image using ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, storage, android-image

I am trying to copy image using below code:

```
  Intent intentImage = new Intent();
        intentImage.setType("image/*");
        intentImage.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intentImage, 10);
```

With this i am able to open all image content.

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 10) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {

                String selectedImagePath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                File file = new File(selectedImagePath1);
                String fna = file.getName();
                String pna = file.getParent();
                File fileImage = new File(pna, fna);

                copyFileImage(fileImage, data.getData());

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    }


private void copyFileImage(File src, Uri destUri) {
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(getContentResolver().openOutputStream(destUri));
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            bis.read(buf);
            do {
                bos.write(buf);
            } while (bis.read(buf) != -1);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bis != null) bis.close();
                if (bos != null) bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i am successfully get path and name of the image .

Now when i run the above code then it gives me error of requires `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()`.

so i have put the permission in manifest :

i have also defined the permission for read and write internal/external storage.

But still i am getting this error.

How can i copy image ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select picture using below code 

 Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                     "Select Picture"), 1);


this will open gallery, after selecting pic you will get selected pic uri in below code

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
     switch(requestCode) {

     case 1:
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
         {
             Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
             String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);  
             File sel = new File(selectedImagePath);
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sel.getAbsolutePath());
             imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


             Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600,370, true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, blob);
                String StrBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(blob.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                imageView1.setImageBitmap(resized);

          //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         break;
     }
     }

      public String getPath(Uri uri) {
             // just some safety built in 
             if( uri == null ) {
                 // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                 return null;
             }
             // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
             // this will only work for images selected from gallery
             String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
             Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
             if( cursor != null ){
                 int column_index = cursor
                 .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 return cursor.getString(column_index);
             }
             // this is our fallback here
             return uri.getPath();
     }


add permission in manifest  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

this way you will get selected image in Base64 to string
```

Comment: From this i am only able to get convert to Base64 but i want to copy that image to sd card also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code-
Image will copy in SaveImage folder in sd card

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
         {
         switch(requestCode) {

         case 1:
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
             {
                 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                 String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);  
                 File sel = new File(selectedImagePath);
                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sel.getAbsolutePath());
                 imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                 SaveImage(bitmap);
             }
             break;
         }
         }

      private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
           File myDir = new File(root + "/SaveImage");    
           myDir.mkdirs();
           Random generator = new Random();
           int n = 10000;
           n = generator.nextInt(n);
           String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
           File file = new File (myDir, fname);
           if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
           try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
               finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
```